# Python3: Search List of tuples for values which have public IP addresses

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sqlite, ip-address

I am attempting to write a script which pulls data from a sqlite3 db and outputs only specific data which is of interest.

**I have written a function:**

```
def get_ip(db_file):
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('select "Computer Name","User", "IP Address1", "IP Address2", "IP Address3", "IP Address4" from SepData')
    ip_data = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    return ip_data
```

**Which yields:**

```
[('user-PC1', 'upc1', '172.24.49.88', '0.0.0.0', '33.4.1.54', '0.0.0.0'), ('user-pc2', 'upc2', '64.24.49.90', '0.0.0.0', '0.0.0.0', '0.0.0.0'), ('user-pc3', 'upc3', '172.24.49.71', '0.0.0.0', '0.0.0.0', '0.0.0.0'), ('user-pc4', 'upc4', '172.24.89.101', '192.168.3.3', '0.0.0.0', '55.13.0.1'),]
```

My intention is to pull global/public IPs and the user affiliated with them and store this data as an ordered list/dict. I believe there may be duplicate entries, so I think the only way to do this is with a list.

If the user shows only private or non route-able IP's, Id like for this data to be ignored.

Initially I attempted to do this within the SQL query but this is only doable as far as I can tell with the REGEXP function which does not come shipped with sqlite3 by default and may cause others to have trouble using the script. I am now attempting this with just python **ipaddress** library. I convert the list of tuples into a list of lists and am trying something like this:

```
pubips = ()
iplist = get_ip('dbfile')
itr = range(1,4)
for host, user, ipaddr1, ipaddr2, ipaddr3, ipaddr4 in zip(iplist):
    for i in itr:
        if ipaddr+i.is_global():
        pubips.insert(user, ipaddr+i)
```

This code obviously doesn't work but gives general idea of what I am trying to accomplish. I am struggling to come up with a clean way of doing this and would appreciate any feedback. Thanks for reading

Comment: This schema violates the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). A secondary table with a one-to-many relationship for storing the IP addresses would give you N possible addresses, not this schema arbitrarily limited to four. Those column names are also a total wreck, some have spaces, some don't, there's no consistency at all. Keep your schema as clean as possible, it's important. Spaces in column names tend to be extremely annoying.

Comment: How does `is_global()` work? Are you sure you're using it correctly?

Comment: is_global to my knowledge will validate ipv4 addresses which are within a public range. The schema is not something with which I have control sadly.

Comment: That's what it does. How does it work? Do you call it on a string? Do you pass in a string? If you're talking about [this library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) then you'll need to call `ip_address` first to convert it to the right type of object.

Comment: I understand what youre saying and agree, the code I have written is more or less seudo code. I would have to add something like
my_ip = ipaddress.ip_address('ipaddr). I dont claim to be a python expert and understand that what I have written is ugly hence why I am posting here

Comment: The documentation I linked to has very specific examples. If you can get this working, add a self-answer with the working code.

Comment: I am hammering away on this now, ill update it if I can get something working =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do a few things, first I would prepare the data better by selecting only IP addresses.

```
def get_ip(db_file):
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT "IP Address1", "IP Address2", "IP Address3", "IP Address4" FROM SepData')
    query= cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    return query
```

next you can process the prepared data using a set to ensure uniqueness, and using ipaddress

```
import itertools
import ipaddress

def unique_global_ips(query):
    ips= itertools.chain.from_iterable(query)
    return set([ip for ip in ips if ipaddress.ip_address(ip).is_global])
```

some people try to avoid list comprehensions because they can defeat their own purpose and become unreadable but I think this is an appropriate use.

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate the feedback fellas, but after some unit testing Ive actually created a solution that better answers my problem:

```
pubips = {}
for row in hostips_lists:
    for ip in row[2:6]:
        if ipaddress.ip_address(unicode(ip)).is_global:
            pubips[row[0]] = ip
```

I needed the user - ip relationship to be intact so I created a dict, thanks for steering me in the right direction however.